# .net mvc js function wont pass guid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

i have been trying to pass a guid i get from a list of an entity. the value is there. what i have is this

```
<td onclick="Update('@item.Pkey.ToString()')">
                    <img src="~/Images/delete_button.png" />
</td>
```

this calls a js function that passes the guid to a controller's action. now i keep getting an error when i submit (click the button) i tried multiple ways of passing the param but it's always the same. `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` i had the issue with a string before and adding ' ' worked but now i don't understand. do i need a library for js to pass guid values?

```
<td onclick='Update("@item.Pkey.ToString()")'> 
                    <img src="~/Images/update_button.png" />
                </td>
```

**Update** 
actually i made an error on the other part of the view where i forgot the Quotes ' '. mistakes were made.

**Update**
for whoever wants it to be more clear. if you get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` during your function call and if the type is a `string` or [converted to] `string` and call a JS function (for example)  you have to add Quotes ['string_value'] or ["string_value"]. 
 If you're have a `Guid` like me the html (generated) would look something like this. `onclick="Update('b15e5144-73a3-4ffd-a02f-01d62768fe3f')"` 
as i already stated my mistake here is my own. i kept editing a different part of the my code and kept looking at another part.

Comment: Can you post what you see when you inspect that td element in the rendered HTML?

Comment: hmm sure i can do that but the issue is fixed it was an error on my side. as i stated but i will update with rendered html for whoever wants to know in the future